# What is the equivalent of user_set_authmaps()?

Tags: 8

I need the equivalent function for `user_set_authmaps()`, in Drupal 8.

What function/method replaced it?

Answer (score 2):

As reported in [{authmap} deprecation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1863874), the *authmap* database table has been removed from Drupal 8; at the same time, the functions using that database table (such as `user_set_authmaps()`) has been removed.

The suggested alternatives are:

- Write your own solution for managing user external authentication and storing remote identities
- Use the [External Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/externalauth) module

Comment: I am not able to use external authentication module neither implement by myself (due to lack of my technical skills). Can you please name few modules using External Authentication module so that i can refer those as examples?